# How to use the pattern "a reverse process of"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have two sentences:

1. Activity A is a process of constructing a product by combining component B and C.
2. Activity X, however, "is a process in the reverse direction" of Activity A, in which it attempts to decompose A into their subcomponents.

What is the best way to rewrite sentence 2, in particular the phrase "is a process in the reverse direction", so that sentence 2 highlights the contrast between Activity A and Activity X?

Thanks

Comment: In literature, this is known as *deconstruction*, in programming, *decompiling*, in other contexts, *reverse engineering*. Do you want to apply this to any particular discipline, industry, or practice, specifically?

Comment: Infamously, the [Haynes manuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haynes_Manual) of car maintenance habitually describe  lengthy, complex and demanding *dismantling* tasks in great detail. Then, when you're looking a pile of unrecognisable oily parts on the floor, blithely state: "Assembly is the reverse of disassembly".

Comment: @DanBron the context is actually in linguistics.
Activity A is writing process, where words are joined together to form complex ones.
Activity X is recognition process, where a complex word is decomposed into their basic building blocks.

Comment: @gbudiman I believe the general term in linguistics is *analysis* (in the sense of *breaking apart*), as in "syntax analysis".

Answer (score 1):

I would say,

*Activity X is the **counter** process of Activity A*

counter: in a direction opposite to: *counterclockwise* ([Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/counter-))

*Erosion is the [counter-process](http://esatjournals.org/Volumes/IJRET/2014V03/I01/IJRET20140301015.pdf) of dilation. If deflation enlarges an image then erosion shrinks the image*

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with:

**'Activity X is the reverse of Activity A'**

or

**'Activity X is Activity A, but in reverse'**

?

If I were writing a technical document that is what I'd go with, keep it simple...